# Configure output path for tNeo4jOutput - Talend Component

Tags: neo4j, talend

I am loading data to Neo4J using talend. Where I can see the default destination location path for tNeo4joutput in talend so as to access the data at that path through java.

Thanks!

Comment: Downvoting since : There is no environment details, There is also no clues of what you have tested or tried so far. And there is no specific question here. Please update your question.

Comment: I think my question is precise. Because as I have written I have already loaded the data. I am just not getting the option to set the location for destination path in talend.

Answer (score 2):

Saurabh

tNeo4jOutput is the Talend Connector to write to Neo4j. So that means that you will either

- write to some existing store files. In the "basic settings" tab of your component you have the ability to specify the path for these store files. Make sure no other process is accessing these at the same time as your component.
- write to a "remote server". That means talking to a running server's rest API, so there is no "location" to specify then other than the http link (eg."http://yourserver.com:7474/db/data").
- reuse an existing connection (this is what I do most of the time): use tNeo4jConnection (to open a connection) and tNeo4jClose (to close the connection). Then you have the same options as above, but they will apply to all of your neo4j components that you connect to it.

Does that make sense?

Let me know.

Rik

Comment: Hey Rik.. Hi.. I got all these concepts. My problem is, I have 60k nodes with 300000 properties and some relationships established among them. Now I want to access all these data through a java program which is giving me wrong output. Please see this link too: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016140/access-neo4j-nodes-and-relationships-through-java)